# How to change xticks in matplotlib with locator.param

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing figures for scientific article.

In such article the room is scarse and the figures must be readable. Therefore an x axis must have 3 or 4 ticks maximum. The default behaviour for matplotlib is to have overlapping plenty of xticks label. It is very painful and time consuming to manually adjust the exact ticks needed, trying to prevent overlapping. I find the command `ax.locator_params` that seem to do the job, but it has a weird behaviour, and place ticks at unwanted position outside of the data limit.

Here is a code exploring 4 different ways to change ticks. The last two are not using `locator_param()`, but are bulky and doesn't work in every situation. How can I make work `locator_param()` or use something painless ?

Regards,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

x = np.linspace(-0.7,0.7,num = 50)
y = np.linspace(0,1,num = 100)
ext = (x[0],x[-1],y[-1],y[0])

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing = 'ij')
U = np.cos(xx**2 + yy**2)

fig, ax_l = plt.subplots(1,4)
fig.set_size_inches(4*3.45, 3, forward=True)

for ax in ax_l :
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    im = ax.imshow(U,interpolation = 'nearest', extent = ext, aspect = 'equal')

### method 1 ####
ax_l[0].locator_params(axis = 'x',tight=True, nbins=3)
### method 2 ####
ax_l[1].locator_params(axis = 'x',tight=False, nbins=3)
### method 3 ####
ticks = ax_l[2].get_xticks()
ax_l[2].set_xticks(ticks[0::2])
### method 4 ####
x_lim = ax_l[3].get_xlim()
ax_l[3].set_xticks(np.linspace(x_lim[0],x_lim[1],num=3))



fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]